# ( Python ) Program doesn't respond to inputs ( key press or click )

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I'm using the Turtle librarie in Python.
My program isn't detecting that I press a key.

```
def jump():
    if player.ground == True:
        player.dy += 10

game.listen()
game.onkeypress(jump, "w")
```

This is the  code and I think it should work based on the tutorials I have seen.
I also tried the code like this but it doesn't work either.

```
def jump():
    if player.ground == True:
        player.dy += 10

game.listen()
game.onkeypress(jump(), "w")
```

Adding the parenthesis on the last line doesn't seem to help.

Help me pls :(

Comment: You should probably register the keypress handler before calling listen(), not after.

Comment: I just tried it and it doesn't fix :( , but thanks for trying to help <3

Comment: You should probably show more of your code. As far as I can tell, `dy` isn't a field of anything in the turtle module, so if you don't have any code that's acting on it, setting it won't do anything.

Answer (score 0):

First I think you should put `game.listen()` after `game.onkeypress()`.
And make sure that you have a loop that updates the game. And if you are able can you post the full code. For more information you can search some youtube videos about making a game with python turtle or you can go to: https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html